# Use DatePicker to schedule notification (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift3, datepicker, notifications, ibaction

I would like my user notification to appear when the user uses the datePicker action to select a date and time for the notification to appear.

```
 import UIKit
 import UserNotifications

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
       }

@IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBAction func disaper(_ sender: Any) {

    let c = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    c.title = "Lets Roll"
    c.subtitle  = "dx"
    c.body = "fyb"

    let t = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 5, repeats: false)
    let r = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "any", content: c, trigger: t)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(r, withCompletionHandler: nil)

}}
```

Comment: Ok, you want to use a date picker. Explain further how the code you've posted relates to your stated goal.

Comment: When the datePicker is changed from its initial date, I would like a notification to be scheduled, as long as its a future and not past date and time.

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried? What is the code that you've posted supposed to do, and how does it not meet your needs?

Comment: Do you want to set up the notification for the selected date? Or is the user selecting a delay from the current date? Please provide some more details.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I want the user to select a date and time for the notification to appear I don't want to delay anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to schedule a notification to be delivered at an exact date, you need to use `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` instead of `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`. You should also set up an Outlet to the `DatePicker`, it makes setting up the notification trigger easier.

```
let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute], from: datePicker.date )
let t = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
```

Comment: How do I declare datePicker.date?

Comment: As I've mentioned in my answer, you just have to set up an `IBOutlet` for your `DatePicker`. I assumed the IBOutlet would be called `datePicker`.

Comment: Did that but there is a problem with .date. The error message states "Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'DateComponents'.

Comment: If i replace r with t in UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(r, withCompletionHandler: nil) I get a error message.

Comment: Why would you try to do that??? You should only replace the line you had starting with _let t=..._ with the two lines of code in my answer, the rest of your code was correct. You need to add notification request (called _r_ in your question) to the notification center, you can't add a trigger.